# Inserting multiple tags results in NULL data

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-tags-input

I am using `bootstrap-tagsinput`, found here: http://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/

I have the following multi-tag input:

```
<select multiple data-role="tagsinput" name="jobarea" id="jobarea" placeholder="Select a job area or type to insert another." class="form-control"></select>
<div class="row mt-2">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary m-2" type="button" onclick="$('#jobarea').tagsinput('add', 'Leadership'); $(this).hide();" id="Leadership">Leadership</button>
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary m-2" type="button" onclick="$('#jobarea').tagsinput('add', 'Governance Risk Management and Compliance'); $(this).hide();" id="Governance-Risk-Management-and-Compliance">Governance, Risk Management and Compliance</button>
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary m-2" type="button" onclick="$('#jobarea').tagsinput('add', 'Offensive'); $(this).hide();" id="Offensive">Offensive</button>
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary m-2" type="button" onclick="$('#jobarea').tagsinput('add', 'Defensive'); $(this).hide();" id="Defensive">Defensive</button>
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary m-2" type="button" onclick="$('#jobarea').tagsinput('add', 'Social Engineering'); $(this).hide();" id="Social-Engineering">Security Engineering</button>
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary m-2" type="button" onclick="$('#jobarea').tagsinput('add', 'Architecture'); $(this).hide();" id="Architecture">Architecture</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

For some reason, if I have more than 1 tag entered it returns `NULL` data for `jobarea` when I submit the form. If however there is only 1 tag, it shows the data on the request data.

The input is marked as `multiple`.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I can't reproduce, your code works fine for me as written: https://jsfiddle.net/gfzybpq1/7/

Comment: Thanks @chiliNUT, but then if you submit it within a form, multiple tags are not passed with the form submission.

Comment: oh, you need to handle array-valued inputs properly for form submissions. The right way to do that depends on your backend. In php, you need to end the input name with "[]" i.e., `name="jobarea[]"`. You should consult your backend language's doc for the right way to handle this. When I use your code with a php server and name the input `jobarea[]` it submits multiple selected values as expected

Comment: I am really stumped with this. It just gives `NULL` as an array. This is my code (its a laravel view) https://gist.github.com/kriiv/e2d5965566ff345bb508605ba77b6e86

Comment: It looks like changing from `select` to `input` fixed the issue.